# Is RIDE 1.5.2.1 possible to work with Collection 3.0?

Tags: python, robotframework

I am using RIDE 1.5.2.1 running on Python 2.7.11 but found some features from Collections 3.0 are not existing.
Can I upgrade upgrade Ride but still use Python 2.7? Or there is a way to only upgrade the collections library?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the collections library is a builtin library, you will need to upgrade to Robot Framework 3.0 to get those non-existing changes, you won't be able to get it individually.  It should work with Python 2.7 without issue.